# Split vector layer by field name

Tags: qgis, vector, splitting

I have a vector layer of 108374 lines  I want to split the vector layer into field names of the layer, which is 17. Now, I want to create a new vector layer containing one of the field names e.g. "OBJECTTYPE". From this field name I want to calculate the distance from a certain category to another vector layer.

I have tried to use "split vector layer" in QGIS, but it gives an error: "TypeError: the sip.simplewrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed".

I'm using QGIS 1.8 Lisboa for Mac.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Split vector layer works fine with me.

Comment: Automation script can be found here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340071/split-vector-by-field-name-and-rename-output-files-according-to-field-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to create a new vector layer, you can accomplish this with a two-step process: *Select By Attributes* and then *Export*. [This tutorial](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2010/10/working-with-attribute-table-basic.html) illustrates the process.

Furthermore, the process probably can be automated with a script so that you don't have to repeat it 17 times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question though, can this be done if "OBJECTTYPE" is a string (letters) and not numbers?

Comment: Yes, Select By attributes work with any type.

Comment: Everything worked perfect! Thank you very much! Kasper